# Custom Select Menu, jQuery Not Working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, select-menu

I am trying to replicate the functionality of a standard select menu by making a custom one.

The problem is that I can't get it to behave like a select menu. My goal is to be able to replace the "selected" text whenever a list item is clicked. I'm also trying to get the menu to close whenever a user clicks outside of the menu.

Here is a link to my JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/9/

I appreciate any insight!! Thanks!

-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as fixing  your code, you need to change `$('.selected').appendTo('.custom-select span');` to `$('.custom-select span').html($('.custom-select ul li.selected').html());`

http://jsfiddle.net/dg7Lc/13/

The thing about select lists is that they are styled by the browser/OS and have several onclick/onblur actions and complicated actions when tabbing to and pressing other keys.

With that being said, you might want to look into a jquery selectbox plugin. I would highly recommend https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui as I have found it to be the most consistent across browsers while still acting exactly like a selectbox.

Their code is complicated (like having a hidden selectbox behind the one being displayed) but it is all necessary. From my personal experiences, this plugin is very easily styled and customized.

Comment: Hello Derek, Thanks for the insight! I've actually used a couple of the select menu plugins, selectbox specifically. I tried doing this moreso as an experiment for a project I'm working on. Anyway, much appreciated!

Comment: Derek, do you know how I would go about removing the selected class from an li once a new li is selected?

Comment: run `$('.custom-select ul li').removeClass('selected');` as soon as the item is clicked to remove it from all list items (doesn't matter that most do not have the class) then addClass('selected') to the correct one.